# What is the difference when spawning a process through node (child_process.spawn) from running it through terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, memory-leaks, electron

I have an electron app running with Node 16.x and Electron v18. On Linux distributions (Ubuntu/CentOS), I noticed that if I run the app through `npm start`, it's working fine. However, if I run the app directly through electron by running `node_modules/electron/dist/electron .`, my app is frozen randomly. It's completely frozen. I have to close the app and restart it.

So, my question is, what is the difference? Is it running the app through npm having a different memory management? How can I fix it? I tried to search around but to no avail.

Comment: I'd suggest some logging to try to figure out where it gets frozen.  That's ultimately what you need to find and fix anyway.

Comment: I logged, but it shows nothing unusual. The app is running fine if it's started via `npm start`, but hang when running it directly through terminal.

Comment: Well, you need enough logging so that when running it through electron, you can narrow down what it is doing when it hangs.